# Runtime code reflection in Elixir

Tags: reflection, elixir, abstract-syntax-tree

How does one extract the abstract syntax tree (AST) of a module or function at runtime in Elixir?

Is there a way to do this in Elixir?

```
defmodule Car do
  def beep do
    :beep  
  end
end

iex > Car."way to get the ast of the 'beep' function"
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:beep, [context: ...], ...}, [do: :beep]]}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for Macro.expand/2 http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Macro.html#expand/2 but honestly macros aren't my area of deepest knowledge in Elixir.

Comment: I think the AST is lost as soon as the module is compiled. As far as I know, you can only get ahold of the AST during compile time, when macros are evaluated.

Comment: Have a look at this resource http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-get-the-ast-of-an-elixir-program/ where they show an example:   {:ok, ast} = Code.string_to_quoted(File.read!("lib/hello.ex"))

Comment: @PatrickOscity That's an excellent point.  I sort of missed the point about "runtime in elixir"

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Thanks. that's one way. I was hoping to be able to do reflection on existing modules (with require and usage of macros in them) loaded by the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Elixir docs on Quote and unquote](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html#quoting) :

> Many languages would call such representations an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). Elixir calls them quoted expressions:

So using the quote macro, you can get the Elixir Quoted Expression (AST) as follows:

```
iex(7)> quote do Car.beep() end
{{:., [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:Car]}, :beep]}, [], []}
```

Comment: I've used this before and it's very useful if you want to build up code that can be safely executed using unquote.